# Should I mention unfinished industrial collaboration in resume?

Tags: resume, research

During my PhD I worked on an industry-academia collaborative project. There were  two major research works that I have done as part of this project. One of those was solely with the  academic collaborators which resulted in publications during my PhD. However, the second work was reserved for technical transfer to the industry and was communicated to them. However, recently the  industrial collaborators have said that their interests are not matching with that research work and I can proceed for research publication on that work too.

My question  is, as I am currently applying for jobs- can I mention  the situation above as "experience in  collaborative work with industry"?

Comment: What is your concern if you mention this situation on your CV? What do you think may happen if you do?

Comment: @numenor I was concerned that as the technology transfer didn't happen, some recruiters might think that I am unnecessarily overstating my collaborative experiences. One might prefer if I mention only the collaborations that led to publications patents etc.

Answer (score 2):

A CV is basically a marketing document. The product you are selling is the value you can bring to an organisation.

If your collaboration was an experience which benefitted your professional development thereby increasing the value you can bring, then it should be put onto your CV *in a manner which gives the reader an idea of how it adds value*.

A quick search for "how to add achievements to my resume" returns lots of information, which should help you to frame this experience in the optimal way.

> ...some recruiters might think that I am unnecessarily overstating my collaborative experiences.

To a degree, overstatement of experience - as long as it's not outright fiction - is pretty standard on CVs.

Comment: Thank you  for your suggestion. It helped a  lot!